# Discord JS - Sending dm to every user in every server that bot is

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js, dm

I want to create a command like `- /announcement` but I want to send message to every user of server in which bot is like:

```
Server a - will send
```

Server B - will send too by triggering one command, is this possible?

Comment: Please beware that sending unsolicited DMs to every user in every server your bot is in is against Discord's [Terms of Service](https://discord.com/terms), and can get you banned.

Comment: If an answer solves your question then please accept it to let others know it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`client.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) to get all the users that have been cached then you can do the following:

```js
client.users.cache.forEach(user => {
  user.send('hello')
})
```

Alternatively, you could loop through all your guilds using [`client.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) and while looping through them, loop through their members and send them messages.

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
  guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
    member.send('hello')
  })
})
```

Note: depending on the amount of users, this will take a long time to finish and will cause your bot to lag, along with the high chance of getting rate limited.